# Create key column of 1s & 0s mapped based on NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a `DataFrame` like below:

```py
df
      A    B     C    D    E
0  test  NaN  10.0    a    a
1  test  NaN  10.0    a    a
2  test    x   NaN    a  NaN
3  test  NaN  12.0  NaN  NaN
4  test    x   NaN  NaN  NaN
5  test  NaN  14.0    g    c
```

I want to create a `key` column which:

- is a string of length == `len(df.columns)`
- each `0` represents `NaN` and each `1` represents not `NaN`

```py
      A    B     C    D    E    key
0  test  NaN  10.0    a    a  10111
1  test  NaN  10.0    a    a  10111
2  test    x   NaN    a  NaN  11010
3  test  NaN  12.0  NaN  NaN  10100
4  test    x   NaN  NaN  NaN  11000
5  test  NaN  14.0    g    c  10111
```

I know how to check it, but don't know how to get it into 1 string in 1 column. My current code is:

```py
for col in df.columns:
...     print(df[col].isnull().astype(int).replace({1: 0, 0: 1}))
...     
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    1
5    0
Name: B, dtype: int64
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    1
Name: D, dtype: int64
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
Name: E, dtype: int64
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
Name: key, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) with [`DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['key']=df.notna().astype(int).astype(str).apply(''.join,axis = 1)
#df['key']=df.notnull().astype(int).astype(str).apply(''.join,axis = 1)
print(df)
      A    B     C    D    E    key
0  test  NaN  10.0    a    a  10111
1  test  NaN  10.0    a    a  10111
2  test    x   NaN    a  NaN  11010
3  test  NaN  12.0  NaN  NaN  10100
4  test    x   NaN  NaN  NaN  11000
5  test  NaN  14.0    g    c  10111
```

---

**Another approach: [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)**

```
df['key'] = df.notna().replace({True:'1',False:'0'}).apply(''.join,1)
```

or

```
df['key'] =  df.notna().astype(int).astype(str).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(''.join)
```

Answer (score 2):

using numpy and list comprehension

```
df['key'] = [''.join(x) for x in np.where(df.isnull(),'0','1')]
```

---

```
print(df)

      A    B     C    D    E    key
0  test  NaN  10.0    a    a  10111
1  test  NaN  10.0    a    a  10111
2  test    x   NaN    a  NaN  11010
3  test  NaN  12.0  NaN  NaN  10100
4  test    x   NaN  NaN  NaN  11000
5  test  NaN  14.0    g    c  10111
```